# Sample size for mvtest in Stata for MANOVA assumption test

Tags: stata, sample-size, manova

I am looking for advice on a specific Stata command - I am analyzing simulation output with MANOVA (in Stata) and want to test the assumptions - specifically (1) the Homoscedasticity and (2) Correlation of the dependent variables.

I'm using the following code in Stata for the test and I am getting the error message below:

```
mvtest covariance y1 y2, by(group) 

mvtest correlations y1 y2, by(group)
```

**Error message:**

```
size of sample 1 too small
```

My experiment is using a Box-Behnken fractional design with 108 treatment groups and 24 sample per treatment group (thus 2.592 observations) - in my opinion this should be enough.

Has anybody an idea what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Other than repeating that there is a problem with the sample size, I don't think there's much to say without more information on your data and code. Maybe there is one group with only one observation. How can we reproduce your error? This seems off-topic for Cross Validated; it looks more like a question on how to use software. statalist.com looks like the best alternative.

Comment: Thanks fore the comment Roberto - as I am pretty sure that the sample size is sufficient and the groups sizes are all the same (24 samples per group) I am pretty sure that the data is ok. The code is pretty much the one stated above. Hoped that somebody had experienced a similar problem - sorry for being off-topic. Completely new to Cross Validated.

Comment: I agree with @Roberto Ferrer: This is better directed at www.statalist.org

Comment: Now cross-posted at http://www.statalist.org/forums/forum/general-stata-discussion/general/586155-sample-size-for-mvtest-in-manova-assumption-test